# Zoom installation hosed in update from 5.4 to 5.8 kernel in 20.04 Kubuntu

Tags: kernel, zoom-meeting

Zoom (57862.0110) worked properly on 20.04 Kubuntu.  I saw the prompt to update Ubuntu when I logged in, accepted it, and received the 5.8 kernel in the process.

When I started Zoom afterward, it now no longer recognized my USB webcam or USB headset/microphone, although inxi still showed both as installed and recognized.  I had to restore the partition from a backup (with the 5.4 kernel) to get Zoom working again.

Is anyone else having this issue with Zoom after the upgrade to the 5.8 kernel?  And can anyone suggest troubleshooting steps?

Comment: @jad OP did not manually upgrade the kernel. It was offered in the automatic updates.

Comment: You can still use the previous kernel https://askubuntu.com/q/82140/124466

Comment: FYI: A default install of Kubuntu 20.04 LTS I would expect to still be using the 5.4 kernel, I just `zsync`'d the current daily (Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) & it's still got the 5.4 kernel; which is the default I believe for all flavors (Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE but I believe the others too) as HWE is default only for main Ubuntu desktop (ie. GNOME).  I suspect you've made package additions that caused HWE to install, as I'm only Ubuntu/GNOME defaults to using HWE.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies, Archisman and guiverc.

I updated via apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade.  I'm not an experienced Ubuntu user, so may have done something I shouldn't have to make it pull in the 5.8 kernel.

I wanted to keep my openSUSE Tumbleweed bootloader, so installed Ubuntu in the new partition with `ubiquity --no-bootloader`.  That makes it difficult (at least for me) to choose some options in the grub menu, as openSUSE is still managing things.  However, I was able to click 'e' at the boot-to-Ubuntu option, and edit in:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrid.img-5.4.0-65-generic
```

... and that got it to boot with kernel 5.4, and a working Zoom.

I might experiment with the tool 'Mainline' -- https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/ -- to choose my Ubuntu kernels in the future.